# Stopping/Starting animations using CCDirector

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

In my iOS application, I'm starting another openGL ES context (let's call it B), so I need to stop the existing one (A) first, then open B, then after closing B, start A again.  I'm so close!

I stop animation on A using:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();
```

That works great! B opens, and displays fine. Then, when I close B, and restart A using:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();
```

I get the old errors of having two openGL contexts open at the same time. B is no longer displaying, so I don't know why this is happening.  Any clues?

Comment: Not enough context. What are you trying to do, two instances of cocos2d or cocos2d paired with a custom OpenGL view? In the former case, try to use a single view and instead use scenes. In the latter case, try to implement your custom GL in a cocos2d scene with custom drawing nodes.

Comment: Note that start/stopAnimation will not deallocate the CCGLView. You would have to completely shut down cocos2d, including director, and "boot it up" once more when you need it again. This means any caches used by cocos2d are cleared. And the fact that cocos2d uses a lot of singleton classes makes such an undertaking brittle, to say the least.

Comment: So I was able to fix my problem.  I wasn't deallocating the ViewController for B until after starting the animations for A back up.  Thanks!